# ColdFusion XML to Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, xml, coldfusion, tree

I need to convert XML created by our ColdFusion backend into a specifically formatted Javascript variable for use in the JQWidgets tree (see http://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/xml-tree-with-empty-nodes/#post-7215 for background information).

What is the easiest way to iterate through the XML and create the javascript appropriately? Due to the complexity of my XML, I don't think that the ColdFusion ToScript will work, but I'm more than willing to use it.

Example XML data:

```
    <Role>
        <RoleID>16</RoleID>
        <RoleName>Role C</RoleName>
        <Certifications>
            <Certification>
                <CertificationID>45</CertificationID>
                <CertificationName>Certification 2</CertificationName>
                <Requirements>
                    <Requirement>
                        <RequirementID>678</RequirementID>
                        <RequirementName>Requirement A</Requirement>
                    </Requirement>
                </Requirements>
            </Certification>
        </Certifications>
    </Role>
    <Role>
        <RoleID>16</RoleID>
        <RoleName>Role D</RoleName>
        <Certifications>
            <Certification>
                <CertificationID/>
                <CertificationName/>
            </Certification>
        </Certifications>
    </Role>
</Roles>
```

Example Javascript variable:

```
var source = [
    { label: "Role C", expanded: true, items: [
        { label: "Certification 2", items: [
            { label: "Requirement A" } 
        ]},
    ]},
    { icon: "", label: "Role D" }
];
```

Comment: read the xml into an XML variable, then transverse the object and create the mirrored CF struct, and serializeJSON() the struct to get the json string.  Let source = that json string.  See: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec133ba-7fd9.html#WS95DFBAE4-DB38-46db-8F18-49154C7088FD

Comment: @Henry - I have the XML variable, and I think I have the CF struct as well - or at least I know how to get it. From there, I don't understand how creating a JSON object helps. I haven't used JSON much. Also there's still the issue of converting the JSON into the specific format required, which I think just leaves me back where I was to begin with - I still need to loop over the data somehow, preserving the parent/child relationships.

Comment: The "example javascript variable" there uses JSON - once you have the data in CF you just do `var source = #serializeJson(Data)#`. This just leaves converting XML to CFML. The link Henry provides gives a start with that, so give it a go and if you end up with a problem come back and update the question with what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: Ahh, that explains it. Thanks Peter.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, you could use the [Xml2Struct project](http://xml2struct.riaforge.org/) to parse the xml into a struct, then use SerializeJson() to get a Javascript object.

Example:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="myXml">
<Roles>
    <Role>
        <RoleID>16</RoleID>
        <RoleName>Role C</RoleName>
        <Certifications>
            <Certification>
                <CertificationID>45</CertificationID>
                <CertificationName>Certification 2</CertificationName>
                <Requirements>
                    <Requirement>
                        <RequirementID>678</RequirementID>
                        <RequirementName>Requirement A</RequirementName>
                    </Requirement>
                </Requirements>
            </Certification>
        </Certifications>
    </Role>
    <Role>
        <RoleID>16</RoleID>
        <RoleName>Role D</RoleName>
        <Certifications>
            <Certification>
                <CertificationID/>
                <CertificationName/>
            </Certification>
        </Certifications>
    </Role>
</Roles>
</cfsavecontent>

<cfinvoke component="xml2Struct" method="ConvertXmlToStruct" xmlNode="#myXml#" str="#{}#" returnVariable="result">

<cfdump var="#serializeJson(result)#">
```

Even if you don't want to use the project, you can view the source for a good example of how to parse xml.